# Program1.pas(12) : Встречено 'If', а ожидалось выражение

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
program division;
uses crt;
var A,B,C,D,x1,x2:real;
begin 
Write('Ввод A');readln(A);
Write('Ввод B');readln(B);
Write('Ввод C');readln(C);
Write('Ввод D');readln(D);
Write('Ввод x1');readln(x1);
Write('Ввод x2');readln(x2);
D:=
   If  D>=0;  then
                      begin x1:=(-B+sqrt(D))/(2*A);
                            x2:=(-B-sqrt(D))/(2*A);
                            writeln('x1;x2');
                      end
   If  not(D>=0) writeln('корней нет');
   end.


end.
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: У вас строка `D:=` не закончена, вам именно про это компилятор и говорит.

Comment: А вот x1 и x2 читать с консоли не нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program division; 
    uses crt; 
    var A,B,C,D:real; 
    begin 
        Write('Ввод A');
        readln(A); 
        Write('Ввод B');
        readln(B); 
        Write('Ввод C');
        readln(C); 
        D:= B^2 - 4 * A * C;
        If D>=0 then 
        begin 
            x1:=(-B+sqrt(D))/(2*A); 
            x2:=(-B-sqrt(D))/(2*A); 
            writeln('x1;x2'); 
        end
        If not(D>=0) then
            writeln('корней нет'); 
        end
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.